# How do I add a new security rule to existing EC2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I have an EC2 Instance already running on AWS with defined security group and rules.

If suppose,I need a port to be opened on that instance,how do I add a new security rule using terraform to the existing security group attached to that instance?

Every time I try changing the port,It is creating a new security group with the same name leading to a duplicate name error

**here I am writing a rule to already existing security group:**

```
       resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule1" {
           count           = "${var.count}"
           type            = "ingress"
           from_port       = "${var.portNumber}"
           to_port         = "${var.toPort}"
           protocol        = "${var.protocol}"
           cidr_blocks = "${var.cidr_blocks}"
           security_group_id  = "sg-061e#####8"
   }

     resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule2" {
           type            = "ingress"
           from_port       = "${var.portNumber2}"
           to_port         = "${var.toPort2}"
           protocol        = "${var.protocol2}"
          # Opening to 0.0.0.0/0 can lead to security vulnerabilities.
           cidr_blocks = "${var.cidr_blocks2}"
           security_group_id  =  "sg-061e#####8"
     }



    resource "aws_instance" "example" {
         ami = "ami-0375ca3842950ade6"
         instance_type = "t2.micro"
         key_name   = "${aws_key_pair.deployer.id}"
         associate_public_ip_address = true
         #security_groups   = ["sg-061e11f267df00668"]
         vpc_security_group_ids = [ "sg-061e#####8"]
```

}

How do I add a security rule to the existing security group?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Terraform code, explain the change you are making that causes this issue and the plan output for when you make said change?

Comment: Just to confirm also - if you make no changes to your terraform code, does it plan/apply successfully without making any changes?  Can you also clarify exactly what the change is you're making - are you adding a new rule, or are you updating either `var.portNumber` or `var.toPort`?

Comment: Security group (sg-0$23232*^*eb7) has port 5985 open ,

Where in security rule I am trying to configure security rule such that it opens port 6556

Comment: The question here is how do I edit or add a new rule to the existing security group

Comment: Did you create and/or edit the security group manually? I've had this issue in the past after modifying a security group manually and running terraform apply.

Comment: You can try inspecting the output of `terraform show`to understand what terraform understands as the current state.

Comment: Currently I can edit the security rule for an already existing VM with security group.

For ex: If I want port 3306 to be open,I can edit it externally using terraform without even logging into AWS (security group).

Likewise,How do I create a new security rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second security group rule with a different name other than "allow_all" That is why you are getting a duplicate name issue. Maybe something like "allow-all-https" for example. You should also create the rule in terraform, then reference it with in the rule resource creation block.

Comment: Thanks Michael,

I have edited the terraform code.There you can see I am creating two rules and attaching it to a security group "sg-061e#####8".

lets assume,I create a VM with the same configuration.It will inturn have two ports open defined in the security rule(Ex: 3306,5985).

What if I have to open some other port now ?